# ROR turns on the Overflow flag

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

I have the following lines in assembly emu8086 emulator :

```
 mov al,00100000b  
 ror al,8
```

when `al` is equal to `0000 0001` the two flags Carry  &  Overflow are turned off,
but when `al` is equal to `1000 0000` the two flags are turned on.

Carry flag is ok - the last digit `1` is in the flag , but why this operation turns on the Overflow flag too?

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: near duplicate: [Overflow flag set to 1 after ROL operation even though it should be undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73623142) - implementation defined for rotate counts other than `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Intel manual Vol 2B](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.html)

> The OF flag is defined only for the 1-bit rotates; it is undefined in all other cases (except RCL and RCR instructions
>   only: a zero-bit rotate does nothing, that is affects no flags). For left rotates, the OF flag is set to the exclusive OR
>   of the CF bit (after the rotate) and the most-significant bit of the result. For right rotates, the OF flag is set to the
>   exclusive OR of the two most-significant bits of the result.

Don't exactly know why `ROR` has this behavior maybe this features may be used to compute a parity bit.

Comment: The reason for this behavior is because the OF flag is intended to indicate if the operation just performed has caused a 2's complement negative number to go positive or vice versa. So in a left single bit rotation, for example, there's an overflow condition if the carry flag and highest bit in the result don't match (it means the number was positive and is now negative, or vice versa). This also explains why it's only defined for 1-bit rotates.

Comment: Thank you very match @luker very good and clear explanation :-)